# Get all combination of two elements with distance 1

Tags: python

I am really sorry about the title but I don't know how to describe my question with words. So here is the example:

Assume that we have a string "123", my function expected to be produce:

```
1 2 3
12 3
1 23
```

or for string "1234":

```
1 2 3 4
12 3 4
12 34
1 23 4
1 2 34
```

I would appreciate any help or design recipe.

Comment: Watch out - the number of outputs for a string of length n is the n+1th fibonacci number, counting from f0 = 0. This rapidly becomes completely unmanageable. Are you sure you need to do this? Whatever problem you're trying to solve by doing this, you can probably take a much more efficient approach.

Comment: That sounds like a job for [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). If you were given the number of ways to translate `130` and the number of ways to translate `1306`, how could you use that information to quickly determine the number of ways to translate `13065`? Once you figure out that, you can base an algorithm off of the idea involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive approach: Take 1 or two characters off the string at each step, and then recursively apply this method to the remainder.

```
def recurse(left, right, combinations):
    if len(right) > 1:
        recurse(left + ' ' + right[:2], right[2:], combinations)
    if len(right) > 0:
        recurse(left + ' ' + right[:1], right[1:], combinations)
    if len(right) == 0:
        combinations.append(left)
def get_combinations(base):
    combinations = []
    recurse('', base, combinations)
    return combinations
print('\n'.join(print_combinations('abcde')))
```

And here is the output:

```
ab cd e
ab c de
ab c d e
a bc de
a bc d e
a b cd e
a b c de
a b c d e
```